# how do i get an image to appear in jquery using a script?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a script I found [here](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/html5-grayscale-image-hover)

And [here](http://www.matthewtbrown.com/newsite/) is my site

For whatever reason, the image is appearing to be invisible, and only appears when I rollover the image. The image in question is the top left image in my portfolio. What I want it to do is to load as greyscale and on rollover, to be in color.

The only thing I can think of is that this code might be setting it to invisible.

```
.item img {
opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: So remove it and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

the element itself has inline opacity style property... remove the css entry for .item img and it should work like you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I set the opacity to 1.

```
.item img {
opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right.
It is just because of this.
Just make its opacity to 1 or remove this class from CSS.